# Arrowheads not handled in copy+paste to external application

Tags: inkscape, microsoft-powerpoint, copy-and-paste, arrow

Using the latest version of Inkscape in Windows 10, I am trying to copy vector geometry from my drawing out into a powerpoint presentation. I have accepted that no technology exists yet to exchange vector data between applications (horrifyingly), but even with the rasterised image, my arrow headed lines have all arrowheads the default colour (black), at the default orientation (horizontal and to the right). This is irrespective of the orientation of the attached end or line colour.

I know arrowheads have been poorly handled since Inkscape's inception, with clearly special tricks required to implement them, colour them, size them etc., and I'm curious why they're so hard to deal with.

Nonetheless, why are the arrowheads not even being rasterised correctly and how can I resolve it?

[image: Illustration of paste issue]

Comment: I have to strongly disagree that this feature is "poorly handled" by Inkscape as it simply utilizes the appropriate marker feature that is defined in the SVG specification. It just happens to be a little more complex than other parts of SVG. Nevertheless, Inkscape produces standards-compliant markers. It is up to the other software to correctly interpret the output and comply with the specification as well. Also, use Inkscape's internal export functionality to get exactly what you see on the canvas when rasterizing.

Comment: Ever since Inkscape came about, the colour of end markers needed to be dealt with using little hack extensions. The fact that the handling wasn't seamless tells me the internal implementation was an afterthought. The fact that this still permeates to incorrectly coloured and oriented markers tells me the implementation has not improved.

Comment: No i see no reason why it wouldn't work. You can allaways make your effects into standalone vectors.

Comment: Making markers match the stroke color was implemented many, many years ago ([version 0.45 i.e. 2007](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Release_notes/0.45)) and the latest versions completely overhauled the marker drop-down, [adding a full marker editor](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Release_notes/1.2#Markers), so the implementation has actually drastically improved.

Comment: 99.5% of the time.. if a Microsoft application is part of an issue in a workflow.. this issue lies with Microsoft. Their apps may be prevalent, but that doesn't mean they are "well made".

Answer (score 1):

The problems you are facing are because your other software doesn't fully implement the SVG specification and doesn't properly interpret .svg files. Inkscape, however, technically produces the correct output.

For better compatibility with older software, try opening the preferences, go to 'Input/Output → SVG export' and enable the 'Use correct marker direction in SVG 1.1 renderers' and 'Use correct marker colors in SVG 1.1 renderers' settings.

Also when rasterizing, always use the internal 'File → Export...' feature inside Inkscape to get exactly what you see on the canvas.